# Angular - binding functions in parent to child component

Tags: angular, binding, components, angular2-template

I have a custom input field as a child component. I want pass a function to the child component, and this function will modify the values of the child component. The catch is that this function needs to be declared in the parent component. (This way the child component is generic)

My **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'app';

 capitalize(){
  console.log("capitalized called");
  // here i want to .toUpperCase() the child component's data
  // in this case, the text entered in the input-text component
 }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-input-text label="label from parent" required="true [onKeyUp]="capitalize" error-msg="Required">
</app-input-text>
```

**input-text.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-input-text',
 templateUrl: './input-text.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./input-text.component.scss']
})
export class InputTextComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input('label') label: string;
 @Input('required') required: string;
 @Input('error-msg') errorMsg: string;
 @Input() onKeyUp: Function;

 constructor() {
 }
 ngOnInit(){
 }
```

**input-text.component.html**

```
<div>
 <label> {{label}} </label>
</div>

<div>
 <input [(ngModel)]=inputData
  type="text"
  name="inputText"
  id="inputText"
  #inputText="ngModel"
  required="{{required}}"
  (keyup)="onKeyUp()"
 />

 <p *ngIf="inputText.errors && inputText.errors.required" class="display-message">
  {{errorMsg}}
 </p>

</div>
```

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this is create a custom event in your child component via `EventEmitter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<app-input-text label="label from parent" required="true 
  (onKeyUp)="capitalize($event)" error-msg="Required">
</app-input-text>


export class InputTextComponent implements OnInit { 
  @Input('label') label: string;
  @Input('required') required: string;
  @Input('error-msg') errorMsg: string;
  @Output()
  onKeyUp: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() {
  } 

  ngOnInit(){
  }

  onKeyUpClient() {
    this.onKeyUp.emit(true);
  }
}


<input [(ngModel)]=inputData type="text" name="inputText" 
   id="inputText"
   #inputText="ngModel"
   required="{{required}}"
   (keyup)="onKeyUpClient()" />
```

Comment: Thanks ! I made it work similarly using ngModelChange.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how good of an idea this is, but you can use `ViewChild` to access the child component variable. With your `@Input` you need to bind `this` to keep the correct scope of `this`.

Some code omitted:

```html
<app-input-text [KeyUp]="capitalize.bind(this)"></app-input-text>
```

TS

```ts
// import your child component and...
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

// ...

@ViewChild(InputTextComponent) inputTextComponent: InputTextComponent

capitalize(){
  // here i want to .toUpperCase() the child component's data
  // in this case, the text entered in the input-text component
  this.inputTextComponent.inputData = 
       this.inputTextComponent.inputData.toUpperCase();;

}
```

And child component:

```ts
inputData = '';
@Input() KeyUp: Function;
```

and same template you had...

Here's a DEMO with some different component names from the default StackBlitz template :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgfsk6?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parent method to child with @Input binding. [check it online](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgtqak?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

#### Parent component

The parent `inc` method is passed to child in `<child-comp [childInc]="inc"></child-comp>`, and the function will update the child `count` property with `this.count++`.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Parent</h1>
    <child-comp [childInc]="inc"></child-comp>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "I'm Parent";

  /**
   * This method will invoke by child component.
   * Make sure the child componnet has the count property!!
   */
  inc(){
    console.log(this.constructor.name);
    this.count++;
  }
}
```

#### Child component

The `@Input() childInc: () => void` is defined to receive function from parent.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  template: `
  <h1>Child:</h1> 
  <p>Child counting: {{this.count}}</p>
  <button (click)="childInc()">Click me!</button>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent  {
  name = "I'm child"

  count = 0;

  @Input() childInc: () => void
}
```